# C# extension methods odd behavior

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I got a really odd situation on my extension methods, here is my sample code:

```
AType anObject = new AType();
AType myObject = new AType();
myObject=anObject;
myObject.ExtensionMethods();
```

After the extension methods, I found the properties of anObject was changed with myObject.  I don't quite understand why.  Shouldn't the extension methods only work on myobject?

Thank you.

Here is how I do my extionsion methods

```
public static AType ExtensionMethods(this AType aType)
{   
    //do something here to aType
    return aType;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `AType` is a reference type so `myObject` and `anObject` both are pointing to same instance of `AType` class, you just did that before calling extension method

Comment: `anObject == myObject`. You've assigned the same object to both variables. The original `myObject` is unreferenced and unreachable. And it will be GC'ed.

Comment: Thank you.  so how do I duplicate an instance properly so I can use extension methods on myObject only?

Comment: @khuang: What *exactly* do you mean? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: because I need to test a number of extension methods on AnObject, and would like to show different result at the same time.  So to create multiple copies of AnObject would sound easy to do the test?

Comment: @khuang: That doesn't really explain what you're trying to do.  Though in the question you *already have* two instances of `AType`, so there's no need to even have that line which sets one variable to point to the other instance.  Based on what's in the question, if you just remove that line then you'd see the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: You are looking for [deep copy](https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+deep+copy)

Comment: You should decide whether you want your extension method to mutate the existing object instance or create a new instance while leaving the incoming instance unaltered. In the first case, you should change the return type to `void`. In the second case you should make a `new AType()` inside the method body, and return that in the end. Also in the second case you need to pick up the return value when you call the method, as in `myObject = anObject.ExtensionMethods()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with extension methods, and everything to do with what you're doing right here:

```
myObject=anObject;
```

After that line, both variables point to the *same* object instance in memory.  So any changes made to one variable will be reflected in the other, because there's only *one* object.  (There used to be a second object, but once you no longer had a reference to it the garbage collector would have quickly cleaned it up from memory.  Even if it doesn't, you still don't have a reference to it anyway so you can't use it.)

Comment: @khuang: Well, whatever the "problem" is it isn't really mentioned in the question.  But either way, glad I could help!